# Avoid memory leak with circular references in Dart

Tags: dart, memory-leaks

I want to reference owner class in its field. It is necessary to dispose these listeners or Dart GC can handle this case?
If owner object is not referenced outside anymore, GC can free up the whole object?
+1 case: 'FilterManager' have 3rd object (service) that still alive

```
class FilterManager {
  SampleService service;

  Val<String> search = ''.val;

  FilterManager(this.service) {
    search.addListener(onChange);
  }

  void onChange() {
    service.filterChanged();
  }
}

mixin ValChangeNotifier {
  LinkedList<UpdateListenerEntry>? _listeners = LinkedList<UpdateListenerEntry>();

  void addListener(UpdateVoidCallback listener) {
    _listeners!.add(UpdateListenerEntry(listener));
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Nearly all programming languages today, which uses a garbage collector, handles circular references without any problems. Dart included. And when I say "nearly" it is only because I am sure there are some language, I have never head about, which has this issue. But no language I know have problems with circular references.

Comment: You've never heard of Perl? :)